# SSIS Data Conversion string to timestamp

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to convert a column into timestamp.

Value sample : ETime : `2020-06-04 17:46:53.750`

What I've done

1. I add the data conversion, edit the input column (ETime)
2. Input and output properties on Show Advanced Editor
3. Data conversion output, choose copy of ETime
4. Change : `FastParse : True` and `DataType : database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]`

But it returning this error

> Error: 0xC02020C5 at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [11]: Data conversion failed while converting column "ETime" (94) to column "Copy of ETime" (15).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Am I missing something?

### edit

Data sample 1.

```
id, cid, invid, etc
33333,44444,abc333334,shoes
33334,77777,abc3333347,shoes
33335,88888,abc3333358,book
```

Data sample 2.

```
cid,invid,bcode,ETime
44444,abc333334,03,2021-01-03 20:08:51.200
77777,abc3333347,03,2021-01-06 17:30:53.210
88888,abc3333358,03,2021-01-04 20:04:22.600
```

I'm joining them on `cid`
It is possible for Data sample 2 have broken data as

```
cid,invid,bcode,ETime
44444,abc333334,NULL,Nodatafound
```

Comment: What is the initial type of the column ? What is your data source?

Comment: The source was 2 flatfiles, and I joined them. This data conversion is the process after join.

Comment: Do you have any empty lines?

Comment: Hi, 
To avoid that, I'm using conditional split. But it still not working. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you share a line of your input ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried with a missing row and got the exception:

> Error: 0xC02020C5 at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sBcC.png): Data
> conversion failed while converting column "Column 0" (25) to column
> "Copy of Column 0" (6).  The conversion returned status value 2 and
> status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential
> loss of data.".

[image]

Now tried without any missing row and its worked
[image]

**It seems there are missing value available or data not in correct format**.
Try ignore failue from Configure Error Output of data convertion component.
[image]

Comment: Hi, to avoid problem of the missing value, I try to use conditional split. But it still not working. It fails on Data Conversion.

Comment: Go to configure error output then set value to ignore failure of the field

Comment: Hi Khairul, thank you for your assist. i've tried this one and it returning all of the row NULL.

Comment: Ignore failure on only date field. check my output.txt that returned all

Comment: after lot of tries, I've figured out that there is "," Comma behind every date, so I have to cleansed all the data again. After then, it all works. Thank you for your assistance Mr Khairul. I appreciate that a lot. 

regards,
Charles